# Writing Abstract Before Article’s Table of Contents

Tags: abstract

In the article document class, how can I include an abstract before the table of contents and still have the abstract appear in the toc?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TOC is supposed to contain everything that has to be contained there without having problem if it is before or after the TOC ... Abstract is not included by default in the TOC in article documentclass... just add an `\addcontentsline{toc}{<level/depth>}{Abstract}` command. Usually you have to compile twice to generate the TOC.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Also, in case you use `hyperref` and not the `twocolumn` option of `\documentclass`, you may need to use `\phantomsection` right before your abstract so as to make the link generated in the TOC point to the right place (`\addcontentsline` creates a link in the TOC that points to the most recently set anchor; sectioning commands generally set an anchor, but `\abstract` is not really a sectioning command and, in one-column mode, doesn't use a sectioning command behind the scenes).